# PHP global Variables within classes

Tags: php, class

I am fairly new to using PHP with classes and wondered if there is a better method for what I'm doing. Basically I am looking for the best way to handle  user errors (like "That username is taken" etc).

What I am doing..

In init.php

```
global $errors;
$errors  = array();
require ...
```

In classname.php

```
class Test {
 public function myFunction($username) {

  if ... {
    //Do Something
    global $errors;
    $this->errors = $errors[] = "Username already in use!";
  }

  else ... { 
    global $errors;
    $this->errors = $errors[] = "Username already in use!";
  }
 }
 public function .... {}
}
```

Basically is there a way I can use the global array without having to re-write global $errors every time? Having to do repeat it just doesn't feel efficient which in my case usually means there is a better way. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You can do `global $errors;` once at the top of **classname.php**.

Comment: You could declare a function (`addError($str)` for example) that handles the global $error array and simply call that in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically any time you have to declare a variable `global` there's likely a better way to go about what you're doing that will have you writing clearer, more maintainable code.

Here are two methods I stick to to handle what you're up against.

```
class Foo {

  // example 1: exceptions
  public function newUser1($username) {
    if( $this->userExists($username) ) {
      throw new Exception("User already exists: $username");
    }
  }

  // example 2: pass-by-reference
  public function newUser2($username, &$errors) {
    if( $this->userExists($username) ) {
      $errors[] = "User already exists: $username";
      return
    }
  }

}

$inst = new Foo();
$errors = array();

// example 1: exception handling
try {
  $foo->newUser1('Sammitch');
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
  $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
}

//example 2: pass-by-reference
$foo->newUser2('Sammitch', $errors);
if( count($errors) > 1 ) {
  // oh noes!
}
```

The one restriction of Exceptions is that when your throw it execution stops and the exception either goes into the `catch` block or, if there are no catch block, the exception bubbles up until it becomes a fatal PHP error.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you inject your `$errors` instead of globalizing it. That way you don't have to track down where it's being set/called/etc

```
 class Test {
     public function __construct(Array $errors) {
         $this->errors = $errors;
     }
 }

 $test = new Test($errors);
```

Comment: Injecting is great, but the data does not come back out! Arrays are no objects, and will not be passed as reference.

Comment: @Sven sure they do. `$test->errors` or `$test->getErrors()`, etc.